# What does git cherry-pick branch_name do?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

What does `git cherry-pick branch_name` do?

Does it *cherry-pick* only the latest commit from the branch with the name `branch_name` onto my current branch, or does it *cherry-pick* a range of commits from that branch, and if so what range? Bonus question: in the latter case, how would I *cherry-pick* all commits from a given branch?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429 answer your question?

Comment: `git cherry-pick branch_name` picks the *last commit of that branch*. "cherry-picking multiple commits" is basically what `git rebase` does.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I bet you know it but so that the OP is aware: you can cherry-pick whole ranges of commits without using rebase by using (drumroll)......  `git cherry-pick commit-before-first-commit-to-be-applied..last-commit-of-range`.

Comment: @eftshift0: I actually didn't know before, thanks.

Comment: @choroba: Well, it cherry-picked the changes from the latest commit and so it did what I wanted it to, but that branch  happened to only have one commit (at least only one on top of the nearest parent), so I was wondering what it would do otherwise.

Comment: @JamesRisner, no, that question is about git cherry-pick in general.

Comment: Adding one more commit and cherry-picking the branch to see could be done in a minute.

Comment: Right, and from now on people can just check here without having to try for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It takes just the latest commit of that branch - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-codegitcherry-pickmastercode.

For the "bonus" question, see this thread: [How to git cherrypick all changes introduced in specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437253/how-to-git-cherrypick-all-changes-introduced-in-specific-branch).